# ZERO SHOT LEARNING

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, deep-learning, classification, image-recognition

I understand that in zero shot learning, the classes are divided into seen/unseen categories. Then, we train the network for example on 50 classes and test on the other 50 that the network has not seen. I also understand that the network uses attributes in the unseen classes(Not sure how it is used). However, my question is that how the network classifies the unseen classes? Does it actually label each class by its name. For example, if I am doing zero-shot action recognition and the unseen classes are such biking, swimming, football. Does the network actually name these classes? How does it know their labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network uses the seen classes to learn relation between images and attributes or other information such as human gaze , word embeddings or whatever information that could be related between classes and images. Based on what the network learns it could be further mapped to the objects and attributes.

Say your classifier has pig , dogs , horses and cats  images and its attributes during training time and has to classify a zebra during test time. During training time it learns the relation between image pixels and attribute 'stripes,tail,black,white...'

So during test time given image and attributes of zebra you need to use the classifier to figure out if they are related or not. Oh , well you could be given a image of a horse too which looks like a Zebra. So your classifier must learn to generalize well.